# Play2 handling 1 request at a time

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am facing a scenario that my application is handling requests in a queue i.e. one request at a time. When one request gets completed another one starts executing and so on. In order to simulate this I developed a small code.

I tried this scenario with default play settings in a fresh new application. I tried to simulate the load and hitting url multiple times from different tabs in browser.

This is my Akka Configuration

akka.actor.default-dispatcher.fork-join-executor.pool-size-max =64

//This is my Controller Action

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._

   def sayHello = Action { implicit request =>
      println("before")


    Async {
        Thread.sleep(20000)
        WS.url("http://www.example.com").get().map { response =>
        // This code block is executed in the imported default execution context
        // which happens to be the same thread pool in which the outer block of
        // code in this action will be executed.
          Ok("The response code was " + response.status)
        }
      }
  }
```

Behavior is same...Subsequent requests do not get into action until previous request has completed implying that only one request at a time is being executed.

Akka version 2.3.0 (Though it works same even with 2.2.3)
Play version 2.2.1

Looking for help from community here..or I am doing something wrong?

```
![Thread details][1]
```

> RMI TCP Accept-0  4:58.094 (100.0%)   0.0 (0.0%)  0.0 (0.0%)  0.0 (0.0%)  4:58.094
>   Attach Listener 4:58.094 (100.0%)   0.0 (0.0%)  0.0 (0.0%)  0.0 (0.0%)  4:58.094
>   Thread-7    4:58.094 (100.0%)   0.0 (0.0%)  0.0 (0.0%)  0.0 (0.0%)  4:58.094
>   Thread-6    4:58.094 (100.0%)   0.0 (0.0%)  0.0 (0.0%)  0.0 (0.0%)  4:58.094
>   process reaper  4:58.094 (100.0%)   0.0 (0.0%)  0.0 (0.0%)  0.0 (0.0%)  4:58.094
>   Signal Dispatcher   4:58.094 (100.0%)   0.0 (0.0%)  0.0 (0.0%)  0.0 (0.0%)  4:58.094
>   main    4:58.094 (100.0%)   0.0 (0.0%)  0.0 (0.0%)  0.0 (0.0%)  4:58.094
>   RMI TCP Connection(2)-192.168.5.29  4:57.261 (100.0%)   0.0 (0.0%)  0.0 (0.0%)  0.0 (0.0%)  4:57.261
>   RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.5.29  2:42.952 (68.1%)    0.0 (0.0%)  1:16.078 (31.8%)    0.0 (0.0%)  3:59.030
>   JMX server connection timeout 52    0.0 (0.0%)  0.0 (0.0%)  4:58.094 (100.0%)   0.0 (0.0%)  4:58.094
>   RMI Scheduler(0)    0.0 (0.0%)  0.0 (0.0%)  4:58.094 (100.0%)   0.0 (0.0%)  4:58.094
>   Thread-4    0.0 (0.0%)  0.0 (0.0%)  4:58.094 (100.0%)   0.0 (0.0%)  4:58.094
>   Finalizer   0.0 (0.0%)  0.0 (0.0%)  4:58.094 (100.0%)   0.0 (0.0%)  4:58.094
>   Reference Handler   0.0 (0.0%)  0.0 (0.0%)  4:58.094 (100.0%)   0.0 (0.0%)  4:58.094

regards,

Marut

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are running in production mode when testing this: `play start`

And double check your thread configuration based on the docs: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ThreadPools

You will need to make sure you have sized your thread pools according to how many blocking requests you want to handle at a time.  You can use `jvisualvm` to see your thread usage.

Comment: Thanks for hint James..Though I found out that problem was with Chrome browser. Behavior on Safari was different. I even did load testing with JMeter and there was nothing unexpected. I still have to figure out why it is specific to Chrome

Comment: I use Apache Bench to throw a bunch of requests at an app.